# How to generate a vector of pointers by its types?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I try the following code

```
template<class B, class... Ds>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>& instances()
{
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> a = { std::shared_ptr<B>(new Ds)... };
    return a;
}
```

But VS2013 refuse to compile it (Compiler has stop working). Any bugs or how to do it rightly?

[more] Please test it by no `Ds...`, like

```
instances<int>();
```

The VS2013 doesn't work. How to work around?

Comment: Post your compiler error. "Compiler has stop working" seems like you are not using the compiler correctly, not that there is an error in the code.

Comment: VS2013 has issues with variadic templates, have you tried an online compiler that uses gcc/clang?

Comment: A dialog pops up said  "VS2013 Compiler has stop working"

Comment: [Works with GCC and Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdf0eb94c85bc55d).

Comment: Also works [with VC++ on rextester](http://rextester.com/VOHK86839).

Comment: Columbo's example compiles and runs without crashing on VS2013. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `instances<int>()` doesn't work on VS2013.

Comment: VS has issues with braced initializers. Try `static auto a = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>{ std::shared_ptr<B>(new Ds)... };`

Comment: @Oktalist get the same error.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what exactly is this supposed to do?

Comment: Your code works fine on VC++2013 update 4.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code using VS2013 Update 4. It compiled and ran OK.

```
// VariadicTest1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<class B, class... Ds>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> & instances()
{
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> a{ std::shared_ptr<B>(new Ds)... };
    return a;
}

class Base
{};

class Derived1 : public Base
{};

class Derived2 : public Base
{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> sp = instances<Base, Derived1, Derived2>();
    return 0;
}
```